# Cassandra 1.2.6 java datastax driver EXCEPTION No handler set for stream 0

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

i had started using datastax java driver from yesterday on latest version of cassandra 1.2.6...i cross checked start_native_transport: true is set in yaml...also my cassandra is configured with rpc_address and listen_adress as computer host name....and with same name i am connected in Client....but it shows this message and after that hangs at .build(); ...

i had also cross checked i had taken all jars i have are as per 
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/reference/settingUpJavaProgEnv_r.html

and i am using JDK 1.6...

Here is message i got :

Jul 17, 2013 11:20:37 AM com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher messageReceived
SEVERE: [mlhwlt08/192.168.2.111-1] No handler set for stream 0 (this is a bug, either of this driver or of Cassandra, you should report it). Received message is ROWS [peer(system, peers), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType][data_center(system, peers), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type][rack(system, peers), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type][tokens(system, peers), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)][rpc_address(system, peers), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType]

| 192.168.2.109 | datacenter1 | rack1 | 000100142d37353634343931333331313737343033343435 | 192.168.2.109

### | 192.168.2.108 | datacenter1 | rack1 | 0001000130 | 192.168.2.108

---

Please help me resolving this problem...

**PROBLEM SOLVED please read below :**

My problem solved..now i am able to create table and insert values in it with java client...

Enabling TRACE mode was little problematic for me for that i removed all slf4j jars from classpath and downloaded latest ones, with that was able to see debug logs...

Actual problem solved by removing this jar from my class path : google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar AND adding these two jars jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar

Root cause was : com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet  this existed in two jars google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar  AND guava-14.0.1.jar...so removing first jar solved it....

I hope this will help someone who will use datatstax java driver without maven..

Thanks for all help...

Answer (score 2):

PROBLEM SOLVED for me...

My problem solved..now i am able to create table and insert values in it with java client...

Enabling TRACE mode was little problematic for me for that i removed all slf4j jars from classpath and downloaded latest ones, with that was able to see debug logs...

Actual problem solved by removing this jar from my class path : google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar AND adding these two jars jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar

Root cause was : com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet  this existed in two jars google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar  AND guava-14.0.1.jar...so removing first jar solved it....

I hope this will help someone who will use datatstax java driver without maven..

Thanks for all help...